# Combining arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

The following array contains two arrays each having 5 integer values:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

I want to combine these in such a way that it generates five different arrays by combining values of both arrays at index 0,1.. upto 4.

The output should be like this:

```
[[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]
```

Is there any simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method?

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]] 

a.transpose
#=> [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

this method also can help you in future, as example:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
#=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

a.transpose
#=> [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
a.first.zip(a.last)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure your sub arrays have the same length, you can use [Array#transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) :

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]].transpose
#=> [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```

As a bonus, it works fine with more than 2 arrays :

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]].transpose
#=> [[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]]
```

If you're not sure your sub arrays have the same length :

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9], [10,11]].reduce(&:zip).map(&:flatten)
#=> [[1, 6, 10], [2, 7, 11], [3, 8, nil], [4, 9, nil], [5, nil, nil]]
```

Using transpose in this example would throw an IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

Using parallel assignment:

```
a, b = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
a.zip b #=> [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10]]
```